# Haml - Add a comment to the middle of a line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, haml, simple-form

Is there a way to add a comment to the middle of a line in HAML?

Here is a snippet from a form showing what I'm trying to do:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, label:        'Name',
                     error:        'User Name is required.',  # LOCALIZATION TODO: t("user.name.required")
                     wrapper_html: { class: 'form-input-field' }
.
.
.
```

Right now when I do this it is indicated as incorrect syntax, undoubtedly because there is nothing to indicate the end of the comment.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, is this bad form I should avoid?

Thanks!

Comment: use # and after it you can write comments

Comment: Thanks, fanta.  I've edited to clarify that I'm actually trying to place a comment in the middle of a line, not at the end. The # is what I've tried and is not being accepted. #, like you suggest, does work at the end of a line.

Comment: I would probably put the comment above the form and start the comment with `# TODO`:  not # Localization Todo. the reason you want to start the comment with Todo is because you can then run `rake notes:todo` in your command line and you'll get all the todos. 

A better comment would probably be `# TODO: Localize Form error t("user.name.required")`

Comment: Rii -- For now, I've put the comment above, as you suggest.  I was familiar with the `rake notes` command, but since I use RubyMine which has a TODO button that does the equivalent regardless of where the TODO is in the comment, I've placed my comment category keywords before the TODO so that I can more easily search for all comments in a particular category (e.g. Localize, Association, etc.) and retrieve them whether they have a TODO associated with them or not. This seems okay since I'm working solo. Working on a team, however, your approach definitely seems to be more appropriate. Thanks!!